# Cannot interrupt a thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I am implementing a Chatting program. Whenever the user clicks "START" in Player.java, it will terminates the previous Chatter thread and build a new thread to start. The Chatter thread has GUI for chatting.

I terminate the Chatter thread by the  interrupt() method. I thought it will set the flag in Chatter thread so that it will be terminated by checking isInterrupted() but it is always false. But it is supposed to be true when I call interrupt() in Player.java

Here is my code:
Player.java

```
    public class Player implements GameConstants{
        /**
         * This listener is used when the user clicks QUIT in the GUI.
         */
        private class ControlListener implements ActionListener{

            /**
             * This method sends QUIT to the server when the listener is triggered.
             * @param e ActionEvent
             */
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){    
                String cmd = ((JButton)(e.getSource())).getText();

                if ("START".equals(cmd)) {

                    //I interrupt the thread using this
                    if (chatThread !=null) {
                        System.err.println("before interruped");
                        chatThread.interrupt();
                    }

                    chatThread = new Chatter(ip,senderName);
                    chatThread.start();
                }


            }
        }
    }
```

Here is Chatter.java

```
    public class Chatter extends Thread implements GameConstants{
        private JTextArea log;
        private String senderName;
        private DataInputStream fromServer;
        private DataOutputStream toServer;
        private JTextField inputField;
        private SoundPlayer msgSound;
        private Socket socket;



        private class SendListener implements ActionListener{
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                String msg = inputField.getText();
                inputField.setText("");
                try {
                    toServer.writeUTF(""+(new Date())+ "\n" + senderName + ": "+msg);
                    toServer.flush();
                } catch(IOException ex) {
                    System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
                }
            }

        }


        public Chatter(String ip, String senderName){
            this.senderName = senderName;

            buildGUI();
            try{
                socket = new Socket(ip,CHAT_PORT);
                fromServer = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                toServer =  new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            }catch(IOException e){
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void run(){
            try {
                while(!isInterrupted()){
                    String msg = fromServer.readUTF();
                    report(msg);
                }

            } catch(IOException e) {
                System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            }finally{
                try {
                    socket.close();
                } catch(Exception e) {
                }

            }        

        }


        private void buildGUI(){
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setSize(WIDTH,HEIGHT);
            frame.setTitle("Chat Room - " + senderName);
            frame.setResizable(false);
            // .... just building the GUI

            frame.add(parentPanel);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }

    }
```

Comment: What does `msgSound.play()` do? Please consider taking the time to reduce your code to a [minimal complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise we are spending time guessing.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I just removed it.

Comment: Okay, removing it doesn't really help. The point I was getting at is that you haven't posted all the relevant code. Some operations can clear the interrupted flag or maybe you are catching `InterruptedException`. At the moment the question is unanswerable because the code doesn't reproduce the problem. See for example this [Ideone sample](http://ideone.com/ZoY6ph) which shows `interrupt`/`isInterrupted` work correctly in isolation.

Answer (score 0):

When you interrupt a Thread, it may throw InterruptedException if it's waiting for some IO operations or like that. Its Interrupted flag will be cleared after Exception is thrown and will be false again.

Comment: It doesn't throw InterruptedException because the thread is not sleeping. The reason why I used interrupted() to check is because the thread is not sleeping. Therefore, I could not catch an InterruptedException that will not be thrown.

Comment: @Fan `Thread.sleep` is not the only method throwing `InterruptedException`. If you have for example something like `catch(Exception e)` you might be catching it by mistake.

Comment: You have called method readUTf inside while loop which is blocking method. So it will throw InterruptedException there which you have already caught, but did nothing about terminating of Thread. You can terminate Thread there.